# Second Order ODE with Hyperbolic Trigonometric Functions e.g. $y''+2y'+2y=5\cosh x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

After pondering for 2 days I couldn't figure out how to solve the SOODE (second-order ODE)

$y''+2y'+2y=5\cosh x$.

My initial thoughts would be to allow $\cosh x = \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$  to get $5\cosh x = \frac{5e^x}{2}+\frac{5e^{-x}}{2}$ but have no idea how to proceed from there.

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve first for the solution to the homogeneous ODE
\begin{equation*}
y''+2y'+2y=0.
\end{equation*}
Let $y_{h}$ be a solution to the above homogeneous ODE. Write
\begin{equation*}
\cosh x=\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}=\frac{e^{x}}{2}+\frac{e^{-x}}{2}.
\end{equation*}
Observe that if $y_{1}$ is a particular solution to $y''+2y'+2y=e^{x}/2$, and $y_{2}$ is a particular solution to $y''+2y'+2y=e^{-x}/2$, then $y_{0}=y_{1}+y_{2}$ is a particular solution to the non-homogeneous ODE
\begin{equation*}
y''+2y'+2y=\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}.
\end{equation*}

Then use the method of undetermined coefficients to solve the following two ODE
\begin{equation*}
y''+2y'+2y=e^{x}/2
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
y''+2y'+2y=e^{-x}/2
\end{equation*}
for $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ respectively, using the method of undetermined coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

$$y''+2y'+2y=5\cosh x$$
The characteristic polynomial is:
$$r^2+2r+2=0 \implies (r+1)^2+1=0$$ 
$$ \implies r=-1 \pm i$$
The solution of the homogeneous equation is:
$$y_h=c_1e^{-x} \cos (x)+c_2e^{-x} \sin(x)$$
For the particular solution  try:
$$y_p=A \cosh(x) + B \sinh(x)$$
Or:
$$y''+2y'+2y=\frac 52 (e^{x}+e^{-x})$$
$$y_p=Ae^{-x} + Be^{x}$$